# Lightgallery dynamic mode wrong index

Tags: jquery, dynamic, lightgallery

I'm outputting three thumbnails with `data-slide` attributes on the page and use dynamic mode to populate the gallery with more images.
It works fine, however when I open the gallery by clicking on the second/third thumbnail and press the next arrow, the gallery goes to the first slide instead of the next.

Demo code can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/ebatron/56rpLaby/4/

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the index property requires a number and I was passing a string instead:

```
var slideID = $(this).attr('data-slide');
$(this).lightGallery({
dynamic: true,
index: parseInt(slideID, 10),
dynamicEl: album
});
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/56rpLaby/5/